# Sci-fi movie where astronauts arrive on a desert planet and disappear one by one

Tags: story-identification, movie, astronauts

As a child, I saw a movie that I don't remember at all. It's a black and white sci-fi movie from sometime in 1940-1950, where astronauts / pilots (to the numbers of three or four but there is no woman) arrive on a desert planet of sand. In real time, the captain can speak by telephone / radio to his superior. But the problem comes, as the film progresses, they disappear, one by one, because creatures (I believe some kind of sand snake; a little like Beetlejuice) hide by moving only under the sand.

There is no robot or android. And it seems to me that the movie begins directly with the arrival of the ship on the planet.

Comment: This is a really good description, welcome to SFF. Note that if you want to add or change anything to what you’ve currently posted you can [edit] the question to do so. You may also wish to take the [tour] to learn a little about the site.

Answer (score 16):

This sounds like an "Outer Limits" episode, [The Invisible Enemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Enemy_(The_Outer_Limits)). Not a movie, but the time period is in the ballpark and the episodes were black and white.

> Captain Buckley has a vision wherein the planet's deserts appear as sand-filled oceans; he then slips out to examine these "oceans". While exiting the ship he cuts his hand; he rubs the blood onto a scrap of cloth and throws it out into the desert. He learns that a Sand-Beast – a crustacean-like animal that swims through the sands like a shark – is at fault for the deaths.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the movie, _Tremors_. I wonder if this episode served as partial inspiriation for that.